# OSError 105 : No buffer Space - Zeroconf

Tags: python, yocto, zeroconf

I'm using a NanoPi M1 (Allwinner H3 board) & running a Yocto-based OS. On my first encounter with ZeroConf-python,

```
>>> from zeroconf import Zeroconf, ServiceBrowser
>>> zero = Zeroconf()
```

I'm getting the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zeroconf.py", line 1523, in __init__
    socket.inet_aton(_MDNS_ADDR) + socket.inet_aton(i))
OSError: [Errno 105] No buffer space available
```

This error doesn't arise when I run it in Raspbian(on RPI). 
I've tried to search for fixes to such errors in homeassistant, but none provide a good overview to the real problem, rest-aside the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the `net/ipv4/igmp_max_memberships` value of `sysctl` to greater than zero.
Execute the following commands on the terminal:
`$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships=20` (or any other value greater than zero)
&
`$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.igmp_max_msf=10`

Then, restart the avahi-daemon
`systemctl restart avahi-daemon`

You can verify the existing values of the above keys using
'sysctl net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships'.

Answer (score 3):

An addition to the answer of Neelotpal:

This [post](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/zeroconf-error/153883/3) includes a nice solution proposal with all options to check for this problem:

```
# Bigger buffers (to make 40Gb more practical). These are maximums, but the     default is unaffected.
net.core.wmem_max=268435456
net.core.rmem_max=268435456
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=10000

# Avoids problems with multicast traffic arriving on non-default interfaces
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0

# Force IGMP v2 (required by CBF switch)
net.ipv4.conf.all.force_igmp_version=2
net.ipv4.conf.default.force_igmp_version=2

# Increase the ARP cache table
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3=4096
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2=2048
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1=1024

# Increase number of multicast groups permitted
net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships=1024
```

**I don't suggest to just blindly copy these values** but to systematically test which one it is that is limiting your resources:

1. use `sysctl <property>` to get the currently set value
2. verify if the property is currently running at the limit by checking system stats
3. change the configuration as described by Neelotpal with `sysctl -w` or by changing `/etc/sysctl.conf` directly and realoading it via `sysctl -p`

In my case increasing the `net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships` did the trick:

1. I checked the current value with `sysctl net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships` which was 20
2. I checked how many memberships there are with `netstat -gn`, realizing that my numerous docker containers take up most of that
3. finally I increased value in syctl.conf, and it worked

And of course it is also good to read up on those properties to understand what they actually do, for example on [sysctl-explorer.net](https://sysctl-explorer.net/).